# Java to C++ translation

Tags: java, c++

I have the following Java code:

```
class MutableString{ 
     private char[] chars = new char[200]; 
     private int size = 0; 
     public boolean set(char aChar, int index){ 
         if (index < 0 || index >= chars.length) 
         return false; 
         chars[index] = aChar; 
         return true; 
      } 
     public String toString(){ 
         String result = ""; 
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
         result += chars[i]; 
         return result; 
      } 
}
```

I want to convert it into C++ code and the array should be a static dynamic variable. Here is my code for C++:

```
class MutableString{
    public:
    bool set(char aChar, int index){
        if (index < 0 || index >= sizeof(chars))
        {
            return false;
        } else {
            chars[index] = aChar;
            return true;
        }
    }
    string toString(){ 
        string result = ""; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        result += chars[i]; 
        return result; 
    } 

    private:
        char chars[200];
        int size; 
}
```

Could you please let me know what did I do wrong? If I want the array a heap dynamic variable. How do I modify the code? I am not very clear about the C++ code for static dynamic and heap dynamic variables. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Just use an `std::string`.

Comment: *Could you please let me know what did I do wrong?* ... so, why is it wrong? It doesn't work? It doesn't compile? It summons Unicorns? You generally want to include such information into your question when you're asking to make things work.

Comment: Simply use `std::string` rather than translating weird Java code into weird C++ code.

Comment: You came up with a horrible hack with a `MutableString` class in a language that has immutable String(s) and now you want to translate it to a language that has native mutable String(s)?

Comment: It is an exercise. I am new to C++. The purpose is to create the array as a stack-dynamic variable and as a heap-dynamic variable. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What is a "stack-dynamic" variable?

Answer (score 2):

`C++` provides a `std::string` which is a mutable string. No need to create your own class or use a char array. You can wrap teh std::string inside your class, to specify your own interface. The `std::string` automatically allocates memory on the heap.

Start of by replacing:

```
char chars[200];
int size;
```

with

```
std::string chars;
```

If you want to do all the allocation yourself, and not use `std::string` or `std::vector`, you need to allocate the memory in the constructor and delete it in the destructor. You also need to add a copy constructor and an assignment operator, adding a lot of extra code.

```
class MutableString{

    public:
    MutableString() : chars( new char[200] ), size( 0 ) {}
    ~MutableString(){ delete[] chars; }
    MutableString( const MutableString & other ) : chars( new char[200] ), size( other.size )
    {
        std::copy( other.chars, other.chars + 200, chars );
    }

    MutableString & operator=( const MutableString & other )
    {
        std::copy( other.chars, other.chars + 200, chars );
        return *this;
    }

    private:
        char * chars;
        int size; 
}
```

(Note: your code never sets the value of size, you need to initialize it).

But you cannot easily resize it, and it always takes 200 bytes, so it is much easier, and efficient to use a `std::string` in this case. The compiler takes care of the assignment and the copy constructor, automatically generating it.

Comment: Thanks. The purpose of this exercise is to create the array as a stack-dynamic variable and as a heap-dynamic variable. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @FredOverflow Thanks! You're right, and I hope I fixed that. The rule of three is one of the pitfalls of C++.

Comment: if you want to make it really `C++`-style use `std::copy` instead of `strncpy`

Answer (score 1):

As it's unclear what you want to achieve, it's not clear how the best solution might look like. As you are asking why your code crashes: You do not initialize `size`. So it will have a random value.

(Btw, your Java code does not crash; you do not, however, set size anywhere, either.)

You have to add a constructor in your C++ class initializing `size` to 0:

```
class MutableString {
   public:
      MutableString () : size (0) {
         // you might want to fill chars with zeros,
         // which is done automatically in Java
         // note that sizeof will give the wrong result if chars
         // is not an array of char
         // better: std::fill (begin (chars), end (chars), '\0');
         for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(chars); ++i) chars[i] = '\0';
      }

   // ...
};
```